# Yarn install command error No such file or directory: 'install'

Tags: ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-14.04, yarnpkg, sylius

I am installing **sylius** bundle and while install sylius I need to run `yarn install` So
While I run the command:

```
yarn install
```

I get the error:

```bash
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install'
```

Comment: Please run `yarn install --verbose`and add the extended information. Are you sure you're running yarn in the right folder (which contains a package.json)?

Comment: `yarn` is not the package you are looking for. You want `yarnpkg`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70184799/301717

Answer (score 1297):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 17.04.

**This solution worked for me:**

```
sudo apt remove cmdtest
sudo apt remove yarn
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yarn -y
```

**then**

```
yarn install
```

**result:**

```
yarn install v1.3.2
warning You are using Node "6.0.0" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behaviour. Yarn supports the following server range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.
Done in 0.20s.
```

Comment: I had the same situation : sudo apt remove cmdtest is the key !

Comment: Had this same issue on Debian WSL on windows 10 and this solution worked for me

Comment: I was having this same problem on Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10. This solution worked for me too.

Comment: I just needed to run `sudo apt-get install yarn`

Comment: Any reason why this solution would not work with docker? I have a base image from Ubuntu 18.04. Running these commands
`RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  apt-get update \
  && yes Y | apt-get install --no-install-recommends yarn
RUN yarn --version` results in yarn version 0.32.0, which fails on basic things like `yarn init`

Comment: On docker, came across this way. Try :

RUN curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash

Comment: fixed problem for me on 18.10

Comment: Running it with `sudo` fixed it for me

Comment: on xubuntu 18 I get error: Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Comment: The reason this is happenning is, that when you installed yarn you forgot to run `sudo apt-get update` after updating the apt sources and before calling the sudo apt install yarn.

Comment: Worked for me on 19.04 Dec 2019

Comment: I have installed yarn using npm and which is very straightforward and easy on ubuntu.
sudo npm install --global yarn

Comment: fixed it for me on cloud9 hosted Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: This worked for me on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera (Built on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS).

Comment: This information is mostly available in https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

Comment: I had to also run this command at the end for it to work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748163/3299397

Comment: Fixed it for me on Ubuntu 18.04 running on an Azure VM

Comment: Saved my day! Confirmed on 20.04

Comment: Had no effect, same error message afterwards.

Comment: Worked for me on WSL 2

Comment: This fixed the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Weird.  This happened to me in 2023.

Answer (score 244):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04. This was what worked for me:

I removed `cmdtest` and `yarn`

```
sudo apt remove cmdtest

sudo apt remove yarn
```

Install yarn globally using npm

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

Comment: This was very helpful

Comment: Perfect solution for Windows10 WSL.

Comment: On 05/17/2020, this solution worked better for me. On Debian 9.9. The accepted answer still resulted in the OP's original problem. (but I was able to npm i without the sudo)

Comment: After running these commands, I need to close and open a new terminal to see the effects. People who are getting no effect, please open new terminal after this[Ubuntu 20.04]

Comment: This one worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: removing the cmdtest using `sudo apt remove cmdtest` worked for me in ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 125):

**Note:** This solution works well on `Ubuntu 16.04`, `Ubuntu 17.04` and `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Try to remove the existing **cmdtest** and **yarn** (which is the module of legacy black box command line tool of *nix systems) :

```
sudo apt remove cmdtest
sudo apt remove yarn
```

Install it simple via npm

```
npm install -g yarn
```

OR

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

Now yarn is installed. Run your command.

```
yarn install sylius
```

I hope this will work. Cheers!

**Edit:**

Do remember to `re-open the terminal` for changes to take effect.

Comment: worked for me. I needed sudo on npm, that's the only difference. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do remember to re-open terminal for changes to take effect.

Comment: Worked for me Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks you, it worked and `sudo apt remove -y cmdtest`  for auto confirm

Comment: When I run `sudo npm install -g yarn`, I just get this mystifying output:
  > yarn@1.22.10 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
  > :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
And no further instruction. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on WSL.

Comment: Install yarn using below commands in Ubuntu 20 machines.

```curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -```



```echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list```






```sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn```

Comment: It's really important to reopen the terminal. If you're on a server, close the connection and reconnect.

Answer (score 65):

The following steps worked on Pop!_OS 20.10 & ubuntu 20.04

1. `sudo apt remove cmdtest`
2. `sudo apt remove yarn`
3. `curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
4. `echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list`
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. `sudo apt-get install yarn -y`
7. `yarn install`

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 too!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, worked for Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS as well.

Comment: Worked for ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: worked for me too, ubuntu 18.0  thank you!

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS as well

Answer (score 48):

With kudos to all the answers that correctly suggest removing the Ubuntu `yarn` package and installing Yarn through NPM, here is a detailed answer with explanation (and, be warned, opinions):

The reason for the `No such file or directory` error from `yarn install` is that you are not using the "correct" Yarn: the software you get when you install `yarn` using the Ubuntu software sources is the "yarn" scenario testing tool from the [cmdtest blackbox testing suite](https://liw.fi/cmdtest/). This is likely not what you meant as Yarn is also a popular development lifecycle tool for Javascript application (similar to Make, Maven and friends).

The Javascript Yarn tool is not available from Ubuntu software sources but can be installed by NPM (which is another development lifecycle tool that Yarn aims to replace - so that's awkward...).

To make Yarn available in Ubuntu, start by removing `cmdtest` and its tools:

```
$ sudo apt purge cmdtest
```

Then make sure NPM is installed:

```
$ sudo apt install npm
```

Then use NPM to install Yarn:

```
$ npm install -g yarn
```

Note: using `npm install -g` will install a Javascript package for your current user account, which should be fine for most purposes. If you want to install Yarn for all users, you can use `sudo` for the NPM command, but that is not recommended: NPM packages are rarely audited for security in the context of a multi-user operating system and installing some packages might even break when installing them as "root". NPM used to warn against running it with `sudo` and the main reason it is not doing so today is that it annoys people that use sandboxed "root-like" environments (such as Docker) for building and deploying Javascript applications for single-user servers.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I prefer not to blind commands I see on StackOverflow, especially when they're used with `sudo`! I think this should be the selected answer.

Comment: +1, and as https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578819/470749 mentioned, I needed to exit and re-open my terminal before yarn would work.

Comment: @Ryan that is interesting - I believe you need to restart your shell if you just installed `npm`: the installation modifies the shell startup sequence to add the npm "global" installation directory to the shell `PATH`, otherwise the shell doesn't see the `yarn` command installed there. You can check that - if just running `yarn` doesn't work but `~/.npm-packages/bin/yarn` does, then you need to restart the shell to get the `PATH` updated.

Comment: the error changed to `bash: /usr/bin/yarn: No such file or directory` in Ubuntu Docker — see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70184799/6404709

Comment: @user598527 as noted on that other answer you linked, if you are using the official Node container, you don't need to worry about any of that and Yarn is pre-installed. Otherwise this error message doesn't make any sense - either you triggered a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/yarn` or you specifically typed it - otherwise the expected error is `bash: yarn: command not found`. Yarn from NPM is installed in `/usr/local/bin`, so none of that make sense. If you are still having issues, please provide more details.

Answer (score 32):

> **TL;DR**
>
> ```js
> // Run these commands (Tested on Ubuntu 17.04 & above)
> curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
> echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
> ```

**Additional Notes:** 
Check out this official documentation/guide for installing yarn on **other Ubuntu versions & to take care of additional `cmdtest` errors**. https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

If you don't have `curl` installed you can install it using `sudo apt install curl`

Comment: replace `echo...tee...apt-get update` with `apt-add-repository -y "deb ... main"`.

Answer (score 27):

1. Remove mistake packages:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge cmdtest
sudo apt-get purge yarn
```

2. Install with npm ([Recommended](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install) way):

It is recommended to install Yarn through the npm package manager, which comes bundled with Node.js when you install it on your system.

Once you have npm installed you can run the following both to install and upgrade Yarn:

```
npm install --global yarn
```

3. Alternative way:

- Debian / Ubuntu

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
```

Answer (score 18):

this worked for me

```
sudo yarn install
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. The user has to belong to sudo group if you want to get the rights of your user on the folders :
sudo usermod -aG sudo myusername

Answer (score 16):

**Using Ubuntu 22.04**
I had this problem from a fresh install of Ubuntu. The fix that worked for me:

```bash
sudo apt remove cmdtest
sudo apt-get remove yarn && sudo apt-get purge yarn
sudo apt update
curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt install yarn
```

```bash
yarn --version # 1.22.19
```

(EDIT: I've tried this subsequently and it didn't initially work. But when I restarted my computer and tried again it did work. Figure that one out...)

Answer (score 11):

There is a name conflict for the `yarn` package (which is currently an alias to `cmdtest` package). The package you are looking for is `yarnpkg`. So, try this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmdtest
sudo apt-get install yarnpkg
```

Unfortunately, with `yarnpkg`, command [`yarn` is named `yarnpkg`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=940511). You probably want to make an alias:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarn
```

Comment: `alias`'ng not possible when the `yarn`  binary exists: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/yarn': File exists`

Comment: @user598527 : the `/usr/local/bin/yarn` should only exist if you already have yarn installed through `npm -g` or some external process. If that is the case - then you don't need to install `yarnpkg`. Please note that recent versions of the official Node docker container already include Yarn so you don't need to install it.

Answer (score 10):

Installing Yarn for Ubuntu 16.04 (not sure if this will be the same as 14.04 as it's slightly different than zappee's answer for 17.04)

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
apt-get install yarn
```

Then from wherever you installed your sylius project (/var/www/mysite)

```
yarn install
yarn run gulp
```

Answer (score 10):

For Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS I just followed the official instructions:
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
```

No need to do:

```
sudo apt remove cmdtest
```

That is only necessary on Ubuntu 17.04.* I think.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

I believe all relevant solutions have been provided but here is a subtle situatuion: know that if you don't close and open your terminal again you will not see the effect.

Close your terminal and open
then type in your terminal

yarn --version

Cheers!

Comment: this was the solution to my issue :cheers

Answer (score 7):

Tried above steps, didn't work on Ubuntu 20.
For Ubuntu 20, remove the cmdtest and yarn like suggested above. Install yarn with below commands:

```
curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
```

Answer (score 4):

Just copy and paste this code one after on your terminal
It worked perfectly well for me.

```
sudo apt remove cmdtest
sudo apt remove yarn
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yarn -y
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS as well

Answer (score 3):

If your **node version is above 16.10**. You can simply run the following to use yarn commands.

`corepack enable`

If your **node version is before 16.10**. Run `npm i -g corepack` before running the above command.

Comment: This is the way. Thank you! https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/

Do not forget to uninstall.. whatever the heck that cmdtest and yarn packages are though, as per the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Also had this issue (windows), the fix was a complete closure of all terminal instances, then retry.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo npm install -g yarnpkg
npm WARN deprecated yarnpkg@0.15.1: Please use the `yarn` package instead of `yarnpkg`
```

so this works for me

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed yarn in different ways and when I run yarn in the console it notifies me that "bash: /usr/bin/yarn: File or directory does not exist".
I go to the path /usr/bin and the binary I find is yarnpkg.
I run`yarnpkg` in the console and it installs all the dependencies.
Note: all the yarn commands work with yarnpkg. If you have any questions we will continue to see them in the forum
[image: execute yarnpkg build]

[image: execute yarnpkg and run yarn install]

[image: execute yarn install and launch error]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deploy to AWS or any other cloud infrastructure follow the link below

[Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-yarn-on-ubuntu-20-04/) this will help solve yarn issue on AWS but still having build time issue thou.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution , since non of the above worked for me.
In my case  there was a conflict between the existing file and downloading file  So to resolve that I followed the following commands on `linux`.

`sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info_silent`

`sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -f install <xxxx>`

`<xxxx>` replace it with the required package

Answer (score 0):

So I found that if I install yarn as root using some of the above suggested approaches that even later on logging in as a non root user it doesn't fix the issue.

This is because yarn gets installed as follows:
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v21.4.0/bin/yarn

So you really need to run yarn installation as whatever user you want to run yarn as since the install is localized not global.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue on ubuntu os and i solved it by using sudo yarn install instead of yarn install

Answer (score -4):

Run:

```
source ~/.profile
```

and try again

Comment: should be a comment not an answer