# The engine “node” is incompatible with this module when installing React-chartjs-2 Chart.js,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am creating a doughnut chart by using chart.js with its react wrapper. It's working fine in the new project, but not able to install it in the main project.

Below is an example of a new project where it's working fine.

[image]

And below is the example of the main old project, where I am not able to install it

[image]

**Error:**

> The engine “node” is incompatible with this module

Node version is the same, you can check in both images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to upgrade your node version.** As you are using [husky v4](https://github.com/typicode/husky), you need **node >= 10**.

Check [husky installation guide](https://github.com/typicode/husky/tree/master#install) and [The engine “node” is incompatible with this module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56617209/2873538).

Comment: Why it's working on a newly created applications with the same node version??

Comment: I meant to ask - Do you have husky v4 in the project where it didn't throw error "The engine node is incompatible"? Or do you have husky v4 in both projects? I think husky 4 is not compatible with Node 8 which you currently have.

Comment: I have installed node 10.15.0 and then react-chartjs-2 installed properly.

Answer (score 2):

From the log, I can see that this is an issue with the version of the node you are currently having. See this line in your log

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with the module. Expected version ">=10". Got "8.10.0"
```

To solve this, you could try this

```
 1. Install nvm
 2. Download another version of node ">=10"
 3. Switch to that the latest version
 4. And try installing the module again
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For anyone on `Husky v7`, and using `VSCode`:

VSCode can use a different shell to your standard one. In my case, it was using `bash` instead of `zsh` - which did not have nvm installed and therefore was not using the correct version of node.

#### Fix:

1. Open the Command Palette in VSCode - <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type `Terminal: Select Default Profile`
3. Select the terminal that you have set up nvm or similar on.
4. Restart VSCode
5. 