# having an issue creating new react app with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to create a new react project, but when I run `npx create-react-app tik-tok-clone` I get the following error

```
    Creating a new React app in C:\Users\mwars\Documents\GitHub\TikTok-Clone\tik-tok-clone.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error postcss@8.1.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10 || ^12 || >=14". Got "13.12.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Users\mwars\Documents\GitHub\TikTok-Clone\tik-tok-clone has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting tik-tok-clone/ from C:\Users\mwars\Documents\GitHub\TikTok-Clone
Done.
```

I've been trying to figure it out for a while now and just can't get it to work.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: The problem is your nodeJS version. It is asking for version ^10, ^12 and >=14. Can you run node --version?

Comment: @WillianGaspar I get v13.12.0

Comment: @WillianGaspar how do I change my nodejs version

Comment: try this: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version. But before, try this post, see it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617209/the-engine-node-is-incompatible-with-this-module

Answer (score 6):

I am was dealing with the same problem and have managed to understand and fix it. I will try to explain it below.

**The issue:**

```
error postcss@8.1.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10 || ^12 || >=14". Got "13.12.0"
```

This is telling you that the `create_react_app` module is only compatible with versions `10`, `12`, or greater than `14` of `node` and you are using `13.12.0`.

**The solution**

To fix this error you need to either upgrade or downgrade your current version of `node`.

One way to do this is to use `NVM` (node version manager) to manage multiple versions of `node`.

To install it with either Linux or Mac you can use either of the following commands

For Wget, run the following command on the terminal:

```
  wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

For CURL, run the following:

```
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

You will want to change the version number in the commands to the latest stable version.

Once you have downloaded it successfully restart the terminal or you won't be able to find it. If this fails you may need to reset your computer.

If you have `NVM` installed running the following should show you the current version of it your using.

```
nvm --version
```

You can then use the following command to list  available  versions  of node

```
nvm ls-remote
```

Select a compatible version and  install it like so

```
nvm install 14.15.0
```

Running

```
node -v
```

Should show this  as your current version if not try

```
nvm use v14.15.0
```

You should now have no issues running

```
npx create-react-app tik-tok-clone
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after running these commands.

1. sudo npm cache clean -f  //clear you npm cache
2. sudo npm install -g n install n //(this might take a while)
3. sudo n stable upgrade //to the current stable version