# node version incompatible, but wrong version is found

Tags: javascript, node.js, versioning

I am trying to use yarn install and do get an error that engine "node" is incompatible because version ">=10.14" is required. I do have installed v16.9.1, so I dont know why the wrong version is found. Look at the terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/NFT/metaplex/js $ sudo yarn install
yarn install v1.22.11
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error cross-env@7.0.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.14". Got "8.11.1"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/NFT/metaplex/js $ node -v
v16.9.1.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you googled the problem and try any? If you have, put links below the post.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617209/the-engine-node-is-incompatible-with-this-module

Comment: this is likely due to the use of two competing installers. Depending on what OS distro you are running on your RaspberryPi, `apt-get` has likely installed node v8.11.1 while you are also trying to install node with yarn. The issue is that yarn is not setting the environment (path) to point to its installation. you have two choices, install node using apt-get or set the path variable as suggested in the nodejs docs.