# How can I solve this dependency error for yarn global add @vue/cli?

Tags: vuejs3, yarnpkg, vue-cli, vue-cli-5

Within a Mac environment, I am trying to upgrade the **Vue CLI v4.5.13** to **5.0.8** using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) as the package manager.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iax9u.jpg)

After fetching the packages, the terminal result is:

```
ted (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error create-strapi-app@3.6.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got "16.17.1"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

Reading the documentation at https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global does not help.

I expect to update the VUE CLI regardless to project dependencies and I am missing the command that the command

```
yarn global upgrade @vue/cli
```

ignores all existent dependencies and simply updates...

```
yarn add @vue/cli
```

finished successfully, but that does not help, due the Vue CLI remains to v4.5.13.

What does

```
Fetching packages...
error create-strapi-app@3.6.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got "16.17.1"
```

state?

Node is incompatible to the node module defined in a local strapi project, right?

How should I handle this and why?

Thank you very much, for your kind explanations...

I am trying to update Vue CLI to the latest version and hitting dependency blocks on the global layer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The engine "node" is incompatible with this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617209/the-engine-node-is-incompatible-with-this-module)

Comment: Thank you. That command does not solve this issue:

yarn global upgrade @vue/cli --ignore-engines

finishes 
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Rebuilding all packages...

BUT when creating a new VUE project via 

vue create projectname 

it's still Vue CLI v4.5.19 active.

if running 

yarn global add @vue/cli 

afterwards. 

error create-strapi-app@3.6.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got "16.17.1"
error Found incompatible module.

Comment: brew upgrade node 

fixes several dependencies issues, but also does not help this issue

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75116916/edit). Thanks in advance.