# Yarn run build -- no such file or directory: 'run'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 5 and following the steps here to implement CKEditor 5: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html

I have successfully git cloned, ran npm install, updated the `ckeditor.js` file to include the Alignment module, but now I cannot run `yarn run build` as per the instructions:

```
root@45899dc31ad7:/myapp/node_modules/ckeditor5/packages/ckeditor5-build-classic# yarn run build
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'run'
```

What am I doing wrong? If I do an `ls`, it appears that I'm in the correct directory:

```
root@45899dc31ad7:/myapp/node_modules/ckeditor5/packages/ckeditor5-build-classic# ls -lh
total 468K
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 128K Dec 24 20:56 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  215 Dec 24 20:56 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.3K Dec 24 20:56 LICENSE.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.2K Dec 24 20:56 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Dec 24 20:56 build
drwxr-xr-x 496 root root  20K Dec 24 20:58 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 283K Dec 24 20:58 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.4K Dec 24 20:58 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 24 20:56 sample
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 24 20:56 src
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Dec 24 20:56 tests
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.0K Dec 24 20:56 webpack.config.js
```

Does this mean I'm using a wrong version of `yarn` or something by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Followed the instructions here to remove cmdtest and yarn, and install it with `npm` and it worked fine:

[Yarn install command error No such file or directory: 'install'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013544/yarn-install-command-error-no-such-file-or-directory-install)