# Module not found: Can't resolve '@reactchartjs/react-chart-2.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-chartjs

I am trying to implement this [chart](https://reactchartjs.github.io/react-chartjs-2/#/line) using the module [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2)
I installed the module:

> npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js

So I have this in **package.json**:

```
  "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
  "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1"
```

I copied the chart code from [github](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/react16/example/src/charts/Line.js):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Line } from '@reactchartjs/react-chart.js'

const data = {
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    },
  ],
}

const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}

const LineChart = () => (
  <>
    <div className='header'>
      <h1 className='title'>Line Chart</h1>
      <div className='links'>
        <a
          className='btn btn-gh'
          href='https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/react16/example/src/charts/Line.js'
        >
          Github Source
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Line data={data} options={options} />
  </>
)

export default LineChart
```

But, I keep getting this error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@reactchartjs/react-chart-2.js'

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone faces the same error, just do this:

```
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
```

Answer (score 6):

I Had The Same Problem , This Worked For Me.

```
yarn add react-chartjs-2 chart.js
```

For some reason, `npm` did not work.

Comment: This solved my issue. Never expected that npm would not work. If anyone having issues with yarn, follow use : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66239058/3921632 and then run the "yarn add react-chartjs-2 chart.js"

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Bar,Line } from "react-chartjs-2/dist";
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurrs due to npm not installing that package properly

```
yarn add react-chartjs-2 chart.js  --network-timeout 1000000000
```

This is working for me