# yarn start command doesn't work while launching the app

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to launch an app (react-app) using yarn start. I have yarn 0.32 installed. When I use `yarn start`, I get the following error message - `00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'start'`. My package.json file looks like this -

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:7777",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^4.26.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "clsx": "latest",
    "debug": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "markerjs": "^1.8.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-overlay-trigger": "^1.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-table": "^7.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am very new to reactjs and therefore would need your help to resolve this and start the app successfully.

Comment: It seems like you've installed the wrong Yarn, read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46013544/3001761 (and in general: research your error messages).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I was following a similar issue - https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3708 but unfortunately, that didn't really help. Therefore I didn't try https://stackoverflow.com/q/46013544/3001761. Thanks :)