# Why is React Native not parsing my yarn version?

Tags: react-native, yarn-v2

I have created a new app with `npx react-native init`. The installation is completed and I can run my app with npx, but it's giving me this error during installation:

```
⠋ Downloading templateerror Cannot parse yarn version: 0.32
⠴ Downloading templateerror Cannot parse yarn version: 0.32
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
⠋ Installing dependencieserror Cannot parse yarn version: 0.32
✔ Installing dependencies
```

Similarly, if I run any yarn command like `yarn start`, it doesn't recognize it:

`00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'start'`

Writting `yarn --version` returns 0.32.

Comment: Checked this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47680012/8196025](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47680012/8196025)?

Answer (score 1):

Yarn may be missing.  Try installing it via npm:

```
sudo npm install yarn -g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install --global yarn
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please explain why you recommend `-g`, in contrast it seems to `--global` from the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461477/7733418 Or is there another functional difference which I missed?

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the outdated version of yarn

sudo rm /bin/yarn (or wherever you downloaded it)

2. also remove cmdtest package

sudo apt-get remove cmdtest

3. download the version of yarn you need https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases
4. install - If you are running Ubuntu - nav to your downloads directory and run sudo dpkg -i yarn_1.22.19_all.deb